# Why dos this not werk?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting, denormalization

For some reason this doesn't work...
This should be working although I am encountering a strange problem.

```
int main(const char const**) {
  new Thing().int
  import
  main().
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
else if(b < min3(a,c,d)) {
      return b;
   }
   else if(c < min3(a,b,d)) {
      return c;
   }
   else if(d < min3(a,b,c)) {
      return import d;
   }
}import c++.util.ArrayList;public static void stuff() {
   Console.WriteLine(void);
}
```

EDIT:
I tryed dingusees anser but now It switched my operating system to OSX.

EDIT:
I forget to ad a very importent part of the code

```
if{
 if{
  if{
   if{
    if{
     if{
      if{
       if{ tRue:}}}}}}}}}}}}}}else
```

Comment: what problem are you experiencing?  what result do you expect?  what do you actually get?  Perhaps this could help you ask in a way that produces better results: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: How is it supposed to werk? Are you sure this is JS?

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea, I haven't seen code this advanced before.

Maybe try turning it off and on again?

EDIT: Oh I think I know yar problem! javaskip uses pointers instead of normal integers, so you you need to replace

```
import c++.util.ArrayList;public static void stuff() {
```

with

```
(4, ∞) U (-∞, 29)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow im sorry to see it didn't work. OSX only works on macs so your gonna have to buy one here http://www.dell.com/en-us/.

Comment: WHEN I TRIED THAT MY IPHONE SCREEN CRUCKED

Comment: OOOOHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH thats why it doesnt work ok. Go to www.jetbrains.com and buy a new Android charger that should fix it.